# Validating form input for data type and range in PHP

Tags: php, validation

My question is fairly simple. I need to verify the user enters 3 integer values, each between 0 and 100, or print an error message.

Right now the error messages work correctly, but when I enter 3 CORRECT numbers, I still get an error.

```
<?php
// get the data from the form
$grade1 = $_POST["grade1"];
$grade2 = $_POST["grade2"];
$grade3 = $_POST["grade3"];

// TEST FOR INTEGER
if (!is_int($grade1) || !is_int($grade2) || !is_int($grade3)) {
    $error_message = 'Please enter three numeric grades.'; 
}

// TEST FOR RANGE
if ($grade1 < 0 || $grade1 > 100 || $grade2 < 0 || $grade2 > 100 || $grade3 < 0 || $grade3 > 100) {
    $error_message = 'You must enter grades between 0 and 100.';
}

if ($error_message != '') {
    include('index.php');
    exit();
}

// calculate grade average
$average = ($grade1 + $grade2 + $grade3) / 3;
$average_f = number_format($average, 0);

// calculate letter grade
if ($average >= 90 && $average <= 100) {
    $letter = "A";
} else if ($average >= 80 && $average < 90) {
    $letter = "B";
} else if ($average >= 70 && $average < 80) {
    $letter = "C";
} else if ($average >= 60 && $average < 70) {
    $letter = "D";
} else if ($average >= 0 && $average < 60) {
    $letter = "F";
}
```

?>

I hope it's easy to tell what I'm trying to do and how I'm doing it. Thanks in advance for your suggestions :)

Comment: What does the error message contain? Have you tried initializing the variable: `$error_message = ''`?

Comment: so, errors if any? what's not working? if not setup to catch and display, use error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php

Comment: Dont check with `is_int()`, this works with php variables but not with user input because $_POST and $_GET are strings. You can use `is_numeric()` actually everything submitted by the user browser are strings. Ill make an answer for it..

Answer (score 0):

**General suggestions and may be the error you get:**

You are barely using the variables without checking whether they are set.

You need to use `isset` before checking variable and `$_POST` type.

Example:

```
if(isset($_POST['grade1']))
{
    $grade1=$_POST['grade1'];
}
```

So that if a user does not submit value for **grade1**, you will not get **Undefined index error**.

Similarly for your error variable `$error_message` too. Because if there are no errors, say the user entered 3 integers between 0 & 100, you will get Undefined variable `$error_message`.

Answer (score 0):

The issue comes from `is_int()` it checks if the variable is an integer however client input (POST, GET, headers, etc..) are always strings. That's why it's failing.

```
if (!is_numeric($grade1) && !is_numeric($grade2) && !is_numeric($grade3)) {
    $error_message = 'Please enter three numeric grades.'; 
}
```

Also, you where checking if any of these values where integers not all of them. So replace the || (or) with && (and).

Also, you compare `$error_message` with an empty string perhaps its more neat to either check if `$error_message` `isset()` or checking if its `empty()` as its easier to read through and even faster in execution as well. But overall its nothing to worry about cause either way it returns true if there's an error.